# Check every list element for appearance

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, infinite-loop

I'm used to *MATLAB* so this might be a stupid question but *Mathematica* is freaking me out.

I have a big matrix with the following format:

```
M = {{A,B,C},{1,{1,3,6,7},0},{1,{3,7,9},1}}
```

As you can see, each element in the second column is a separate list again. These separate lists contain integers, so it's no problem to get back to them. For example if I use `MemberQ[M[[2,2]],1]` it returns `True`, as it's supposed to do.

What I want to do now: my Matrix is a little longer, contains approx. 5'000 rows.
I want to check every seperate list mentioned above for the appearance of a specific integer, as I did above with the `MemberQ`.

As a result it should give me something like the following (taking `M` as example): `{True,False}`.

I thought that's supposed to be easy with a for-loop as it is in *MATLAB*, but *Mathematica* always stops when condition is not met...

Looking forward to your answers. Please state if I need to clarify my question!

Comment: Please be precise in the problem description.  The second row of this matrix is `{1,{1,3,6,7},0}`.  The elements of the second row are *not* lists, contradicting what you said.  `memberQ[M[2,2],1]` is not correct Mathematica code and won't return `True`.  If you mean `MemberQ[M[[2,2]],1]`, please write it as such.

Comment: Sorry for that, recognized it myself, already edited. Meant second column, and memberQ now correct.

Comment: So `B` is a list then?

Comment: Not a Mma matrix (see MatrixQ) ... but a tensor.

Comment: Is `MemberQ[#[[2]], 1] & /@ M` what you are looking for?

Comment: You can try `MemberQ[#, 1] & /@ M[[All, 2]]`.

Comment: @Öskå When I looked at the question, it was not the only problem in that expression, and it was not the only confusing thing in the question.  When these pile up, they make the question too confusing, and it becomes less clear where the problems come from.  Now all these problems are corrected and the question is clear.

Comment: @Szabolcs Well, I think our two comments above now answer the question. Or we are both wrong ;o)

Comment: @Öskå Post an answer!

Comment: You are BOTH right:)) it's perfect! I tried almost the same but not exactly, so I could never get a list. Can anyone explain me why the "&" sign is needed there? that's why I'm not getting yet. Is it for the matrix that you state at the end? And @Öskå: do I always have to take "#" before the brackets if I want to take every row? I tried it like this: MemberQ[M[[#,2]],1].

Comment: @Phily If you come from MATLAB and you're e beginner, just keep two things in mind: 1. Never use `For`, it makes things unreadable, it's slow, it's error-prone.  Use `Do` instead, which is a better equivalent of MATLAB's `for`.  2. If you need to collect results from a `Do`, use `Table`.  It has the same syntax as `Do`, but it collects results into a `Table`, and it's much more commonly used than `Do`.  This will start you on the road for using functional constructs.  Many uses of `Table` can be replaced with other functional approach, such as `Map` (a bit like `arrayfun`).

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) for the particular issue with `#` and `&`.

Comment: @Phily To be fair, `For` has its uses, but I think that while you're a beginner, it's a good approach simply not to use it. If you get more proficient in Mathematica, you'll see when `For` is more appropriate anyway.  This problem could be written using `Table` as `Table[MemberQ[M[[i,2]], 1], {i, 1, Length[M]}]`.  It's better as `Table[MemberQ[row[[2]], 1], {row, M}]`.  It's even better as the `Map` (`/@`) we wrote above.  Just trying to move step by step from a for-loop-like style to `Map`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks very much for the tipp, I'll keep that in mind for the future. Already thought the for-function isn't that comfortable to work with in Mathematica:)

Comment: Also check out [MATLink](http://matlink.org).  It'll let you call any existing MATLAB code you might have from Mathematica (of course there's some performance overhead for each call).

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks very very much for your kind help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is to do `Map` `MemberQ` over the second column (a.k.a. `[[2]]`) of each lines:

```
M = {{A,B,C},{1,{1,3,6,7},0},{1,{3,7,9},1}}
MemberQ[#[[2]], 1] & /@ M
```

> {False, True, False}

An equivalent would be (thanks [to Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50783/check-every-list-element-for-appearance/50785?noredirect=1#comment149754_50785)):

```
MemberQ[#2, 1] & @@@ M
```

Comment: Slightly cleaner and faster: `MemberQ[#2, 1] & @@@ M`  (+1)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm surprised that it's faster (haven't tried), but it's definitely more appealing to me.

Comment: @Szabolcs The statement only holds for unpacked data, but if we're working with packed data numeric methods are likely to be much faster (as I'm sure you know; stating it for others).